# WPF DataGrid AutoSize Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I`ve recently been trying to get text wrapping working within a WPF (C/4.0) DataGrid, and no matter which solution I implement (All use some form of TextBlock inside a template with wrapping) it confuses the auto height of the grid and results in excessive white space (Set to Yellow for visibility sake) at the bottom of the grid.

My Code: (Commented code is alternate solution to text wrapping, but still results in excessive space)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" Name="dgFamilyHistories" IsReadOnly="True" 
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Patient.FamilyHistories}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible"
                      GridLinesVisibility="All">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
            </Style>
            <!--<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Border Name="border">
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <DockPanel>
                                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"  
                                                         Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>-->
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow" />
        </DataGrid.Background>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding DateEntered, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" Width="85"/>
            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Relation" Binding="{Binding Relation}"/>-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Relation">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Relation}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Illness" Binding="{Binding Illness}"/>-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Illness">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Illness}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Health" Binding="{Binding Health}"/>-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Health">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Health}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Birth Date" Binding="{Binding DateOfBirth, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" Width="85"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Death Date" Binding="{Binding DateOfDeath, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" Width="85"/>
            <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Death Cause" Binding="{Binding CauseOfDeath}"/>-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Death Cause">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=CauseOfDeath}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" Width="50"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Name="lblDetails" Content="{Binding Path=Comments}" ContentStringFormat="{}Comments: {0}" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Comments, Converter={Converters:IsNullStringConverter}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="lblDetails" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Background="Blue">

    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Use this way, to expand your datagrid with proper height and width
   <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{DynamicResource name}"  Width="*" 
                                                           CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="Name"
                                                           HeaderStyle="{StaticResource StaffDgColoumnHeaderStyle}">
                                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource RowTextblockStyle}" >`enter code here`
                                                <Hyperlink>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Name}"
                                                               TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                                                </Hyperlink>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                            <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{DynamicResource sft}"  Width="*" 
                                                           CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="ShiftName"
                                                           HeaderStyle="{StaticResource StaffDgColoumnHeaderStyle}">
                                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShiftName}" ToolTip="{Binding ShiftName}"
                                                       Style="{StaticResource RowTextblockStyle}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>

See Width ="*" Or Use Width ="Auto" or Width = "20*" as per as your requirement.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've encountered that too, must be a bug. The issue is really not the Wrapping itself but rather that as soon a cell gets smaller than it was, then the Height of DataGrid won't update until it's resized for whatever reason (change size of Window or whatever). I don't have a good solution to this problem but here is some sort of workaround.

**Update**

Optimized version, using DataGridColumn's instead of TextBlocks. Uses an Attached Property WrapColumn (defaults to false) to know the Columns that wrap.

Xaml. Add local:MainWindow.WrapColumn="True" for every wrapping Column.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Health"
                        local:MainWindow.WrapColumn="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Health}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Add an Attached Property

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty WrapColumnProperty =
          DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("WrapColumn",
                                              typeof(bool),
                                              typeof(MainWindow));
    public static void SetWrapColumn(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(WrapColumnProperty, value);
    }
    public static bool GetWrapColumn(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(WrapColumnProperty);
    }
```

Add a listener for ActualWidth changes for every DataGridColumn that has WrapColumn set to true

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DependencyPropertyDescriptor dependencyPropertyDescriptor =
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(DataGridColumn.ActualWidthProperty, typeof(DataGridColumn));

    if (dependencyPropertyDescriptor != null)
    {
        foreach (DataGridColumn column in c_dataGrid.Columns)
        {
            if (GetWrapColumn(column) == true)
            {
                dependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(column, DataGridColumn_ActualWidthChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    void DataGridColumn_ActualWidthChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c_dataGrid.Width = c_dataGrid.ActualWidth - 1;
        EventHandler eventHandler = null;
        eventHandler = new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            c_dataGrid.Width = double.NaN;
            c_dataGrid.LayoutUpdated -= eventHandler;
        });
        c_dataGrid.LayoutUpdated += eventHandler;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: This solution works, but the auto size still gets confused when printing with a flow document. If the flow document triggers a resize its height displays correctly but all columns are squished.

Comment: Saw you approved and the disapproved it a while after so I figured something wasn't playing ball. So the columns end up with minimal width or what is the effect?

Comment: pretty much, basiclly I'm taking the grid and putting it in a flow document which I'm then printing. Essentially what happens is that as soon as the flow document exceeds one page the first datagrid on it gets messed up. (The overall grid is the correct width and so are the headers, but toe cells are all squished to the left. Ill try and post a screen shot.

Comment: Sorry no let me revise that, the grid is the correct width but the headers & cells are squished to the left (Probably to the min width)

Comment: Here's a link to a screen shot http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/4483245/img/4483245.jpg

Comment: From what I can tell its not tripping the Size_Changed Event when the flow document screws it up.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to reproduce this. Got any suggestion?

Comment: not really, I've noticed a similar effect if I mess aroung with the colum width property on my flow document.

Comment: It only ever appears to crop up when the BlockUIContainers exceed one page, then the first datagrid gets messed up the others are all fine. Basic flow document structure: <Flow Document> <BlockUIContainer> <Control Containing DataGrid/> <BlockUIContainer/><Flow document/>

Comment: I've come up with a really hack job workaround. In my code the Actual Width of a cell is set to 20 whenever things get messed up. By checking if the values 20 and ignoring it if it is your code then works as expected.

Comment: Not really there are huge performance issues, esp with more than 50 rows.

Comment: @FA Servers: I updated my example with an optimized version. Should be faster